What material to use for conductors in electrostatic simulation (FEMM)
I'm setting up an electrostatic problem for the first time and I'm a bit confused about how to handle conductive materials in FEMM (or in general, really). E.g., I'm modeling a cross-section of a copper wire with a circle. Allegedly, conductors should not be assigned materials, since their ϵ is basically infinity. This seems to be in line with this ES tutorial here, where apparently conductors are not assigned materials (see section 3). However, if I do this, FEMM complains when I try to run the simulation with "Material properties have not been defined for all regions...". In several tutorials on Youtube on the other hand, "Copper" materials are created with ϵ=1. Why is this? Can anybody shed some light?

Copper and aluminum have \$\epsilon_r=1\$ and a quite high conductivity. Using \$\epsilon_r=\infty\$ is a work around (which works, of course).
Anyway, the thing is that the electric field is null inside conductors (for electrostatic formulation). Thus, you don't need to model it. Particularly, in FEMM 4.2, you can choose <NoMesh> for those regions. The voltage can then be defined through a "Boundary Condition" on the conductor' surface or through a "Conductor" property (which can be set as voltage or charge). I like conductors because it computes capacitances automatically in the post processing.

Thanks a lot for the clarification. I've got one question, though, since I'm really new to this and don't have a good Physics background: so you wrote $\epsilon_r=1$ for conductors and $\epsilon_r=\infty$ is a workaround. I read it exactly the other way around. Is this a typo on your end or did I get this wrong? Since $E=0$ in a conductor, $\kappa=\infty$, hence $\epsilon_r=\infty$?

I wrote it right. Copper and aluminum has epsilon_r=1. You can google it, there is no doubt on that. Now, if you look to the electrostatic formulation, there isn't any accounting for the conductivity. FEMM 4.2 allows you to set a  inside a floating conductor, for instance. Some programs don't have this option. In that case, applying epsilon_r=inf is a workaround.

Got it, thanks. I just rediscovered where I got this from: https://www.ipcb.com/pcb-blog/10194.html But, seems to be nonsense, then.
